# When to use parent pointers in trees?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

There are many problems in which we need to find the parents or ancestors of a node in a tree repeatedly. So, in those scenarios, instead of finding the parent node at run-time, a less complicated approach seems to be using parent pointers. This is time efficient but increase space. Can anyone suggest, in which kind of problems or scenarios, it is advisable to use parent pointers in a tree?

For example - distance between two nodes of a tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> using parent pointers. This is time efficient but increase space.

A classic trade-off in Computer Science.

> In which kind of problems or scenarios, it is advisable to use parent pointers in a tree?

In cases where finding the parents in runtime would cost much more than having pointers to the parents.

Now, one has to understand what cost means. You mentioned the trade-off yourself: One should think whether or not is worth to spend some extra memory to store the pointers, in order speedup your program.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the scenarios that I can think of, where having a parent pointer saved in a node could help improve out time complexity

```
-> Ancestors of a given node in a binary tree
-> Union Find Algorithm
-> Maintain collection of disjoint sets
-> Merge two sets together
```

Now according to me in general having a parent pointer for any kind of tree problem or trie problem would make your traversal up-down or bottom-up easier.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just cases where you need efficient bottom-up traversal outside the context of top-to-bottom traversal as a generalized answer.

As a concrete example, let's say you have a graphics software which uses a quad-tree to efficiently draw only elements on screen and let users select elements efficiently that they click on or marquee select.

However, after the users select some elements, they can then delete them. Deleting those elements would require the quad-tree to be updated in a bottom-up sort of fashion, updating parent nodes in response to leaf nodes becoming empty. But the elements we want to delete are stored in a different selection list data structure. We didn't arrive at the elements to delete through a top-to-bottom tree traversal.

In that case it might not only be a lot simpler to implement but also computationally efficient to store pointers/indices from child to parent, and possibly even element to leaf, since we're updating the tree in response to activity that occurred at the leaves in a bottom-up fashion. Otherwise you'd have to work from top to bottom and then back up again somehow, and the removal of such elements would have to be done centrally through the tree working in a top-to-bottom-and-back-up-again fashion.

To me the most useful cases I've found would be cases where the tree needs to update as a result of activity occurring in the leaves from the "outside world", so to speak, not in the middle of descending down the tree, and often involving two or more data structures, not just that one tree itself.

Another example is like, say you have a GUI widget which, upon being clicked, minimizes its parent widget. But we don't descend down the tree to determine what widget is clicked. We use another data structure for that like a spatial hash. So in that case we want to get from child widget to parent widget, but we didn't arrive at the child widget through top-down tree traversal of the GUI hierarchy so we don't have the parent widget readily available in a stack, e.g. We arrived at the child widget being clicked on through a spatial query into a different data structure. In that case we could avoid working our way down from root to child's parent if the child simply stored its parent.